# Sendgrid Emails - Result handling and tracking

Tags: c#, email, smtp, sendgrid

I am looking at the c# .Net libraries from sendgrid to send emails from my applications. I can only see a DeliverAsync method within Web and I don't see any Deliver method as shown in some examples..

1) if I want to know the result of that email(success/Failed/smtp status codes), How and where do I get that information? Is there any result object?

2)  if I want to track the status of the email later like whether it sent to spam or user opened it How can I do that. DO they have any tracking number/id for the email which I can get from the result object and use it later to get status through their API?

I am new to using Sendgrid libraries. So any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no result object in the sending of the message, since that can take some time.
The best way is to leverage the [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html), so that you can receive POSTs with JSON data about your messages. you can even leverage [unique_args](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html) to positively relate events to a particular message.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any documentation or examples on how to add unique arguments to the email while sending it to sendgrid (C#) ? I assume I can use the same argument from the webhook post message to match with my original email message later.

Comment: I don't know C#, but this is in the library: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/e75eaee35beaf9170505db626408021c50307289/SendGrid/SendGridMail/SendGrid.cs#L242

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you might want to try a templating API, like sendwithus. They'll integrate with SendGrid events for you and give a UI showing events and status of every email.